# How to use SD card's full storage capacity?

Tags: sd-card

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

I just bought a new 32GB mini SD card to make more space for my video files and put them into my phone.

When I turn on my phone the system just mounts new SD card to `/sdcard0`,  then it begin to use it as system internal storage. Even when I try to change default write disk to internal storage, it shows as `/sdcard1`.

How do I use SD card in full space?

System: Android 5.0

Kernel ver. 3.10.54

Comment: I may have ended up changing the intent of this question. Editors are encouraged to correct my edit, because I had difficulty understanding this post, but it was in dire need of an edit, so I had to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Your device is automatically using the SD Card as internal storage, this makes the mount directory change from `storage/sdcard1` to `storage/sdcard0`, this is how Android utilises the SD Card as Adoptable Internal Storage...

You will still have the space you want,
If you would like to continue using internal storage as your primary storage location, you should select Phone Storage.. This will use a Fake SD Card emulated on User Data, Mounting the Fake SD Card  @ `/storage/emulated/legacy` and `storage/sdcard0`, however if you want to use the real SD Card as internal storage, it will mount the Fake SD Card @ `storage/sdcard1` and the Real SD Card @ `storage/sdcard0` ...

The main directory that changes is the `sdcard` directory, If you send a file to `/sdcard/` it will write to the External Storage selection, either Real or Fake SD Card, depending on your selection.

I'm not sure how you are planning to use the card, but I imagine you may have thought the OS merged the available storage into a single larger storage device.. this isn't the case.